# Как отловить объект Response перед ответом в laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть задача глобально контролировать то, что будет возвращаться приложением (laravel5/lumen). 
На примере контроллера, это может быть примерно так:

```
echo '...';
return '...';
return view();
return response('...');
...
```

Необходимо в каком-то глобальном x-месте поставить что-то типа:

```
if (!$response instedOf Response) {
...
}
```

Чтобы была возможность возвращать только один объект Response (кастомную обертку над коробочным).

Раньше в laravel были глобальные стобытия, на которые можно было подписаться, однако я ничего аналогичного не нашел для 5 версии.

Comment: Ок что мешает в базовом классе контроллера создать метод который будет контролировать вывод ?

Comment: @Orange_shadow, кпд стремиться к 0. Так-как нет никакого контроля, поэтому мне ничто не мешает вызвать что-то другое, а не свой метод. Когда есть команда - это не очень хорошо.

Comment: Странно тогда что в документации вообще предлагают создавать свой ответ: [Response Macros](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#response-macros)

Comment: А еще, я вот не уверен, но в middleware, есть обработчик после того как отработает приложение.